# Обновление страницы Angular 2(4)

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Доброго времени суток! 
Есть проблема с роутингом в Angular 2.
При обновлении страницы, на какой бы я ни был, перебрасывает на главную. То есть на home.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
{path: 'registration', loadChildren: 
 './registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'},
```

];

На бэкенде у меня Java Spring.
И для корректного отображения страниц, вынужден использовать { useHash : true }, который добавляет hash в url. 
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score -1):

попробуй просто написать path: ' ' на последнем месте

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
{path: 'registration', loadChildren: 
 './registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Точно не помню, но по моему именно так тогда и решил)